# Probability of 6 independent events in excel

Tags: excel, probability

I want to calculate the probability of 6 independent events in excel.  I know the general formula to do this howver it is very cumbersome to implement in excel.
[image: Prob of union]

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The equation in your question suggests that you are asking for the probability of **one or more** of the events happening. This is the same as asking for the probability of "not none of them" happening. In Excel, you can calculate this using the following formula:

```
=1-PRODUCT(1-A1,1-A2,1-A3,1-A4,1-A5,1-A6)
```

(Here I am assuming that the probability of the events are given in cells `A1:A6`.)

However, if instead you are asking for the probability of **all** of the events happening, it's just the product of their individual probabilities:

```
=PRODUCT(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)
```